# How to change the order of the default gateway with systemd-networkd

Tags: systemd

I have an lxd container configured with two network interfaces (using systemd-networkd).

The first one has a static IP address:

```
testuser@lxd-7e5cbece-180b-427f-a8b1-b2c12f6e9d79:~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/20-net0.network 
[Match]
Name=net0

[Network]
Address=162.132.242.249/26
Gateway=162.132.192.252
DNS=162.132.192.252
DNS=162.132.170.6
```

And the default interface from lxd (which uses DHCP):

```
testuser@lxd-7e5cbece-180b-427f-a8b1-b2c12f6e9d79:~$ cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network 
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
SendHostname=True
```

Now the problem is that the routing table is generated with `162.132.192.252` (from net0) as the default gateway, but I would like the gateway from eth0 to be the default gateway.

```
testuser@lxd-7e5cbece-180b-427f-a8b1-b2c12f6e9d79:~$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         162.132.242.252 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 net0
0.0.0.0         10.245.111.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
10.245.111.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.245.111.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth0
162.132.242.192 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 net0
```

**1) Why is the routing table generated in that order? (first net0 and then eth0)**

**2) Is it possible to change the order of the default gateways?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, you can actually do this using metrics. Instead of defining the default Gateway in the [Network] section you can add a default route with a lower metric to the static interface:

```
[Match]
Name=net0

[Network]
Address=162.132.242.249/26
DNS=162.132.192.252
DNS=162.132.170.6

[Route]
Gateway=162.132.192.252
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Metric=1024
```

After this you can do the same for a DHCP interface (note that you don't have to define the Gateway because this will be provided by your DHCP server):

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
SendHostname=True
UseDomains=True

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Metric=1000
```

Now you get the desired routing table with the eth0 interface as default gateway:

```
> ip route list
default dev eth0 proto static metric 1000 
default dev net0 proto static metric 1024 
default via 10.245.111.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.245.111.96 metric 1024 
10.245.111.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.245.111.96 
10.245.111.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.245.111.96 metric 1024 
162.132.242.192/26 dev net0 proto kernel scope link src 162.132.242.249
```

Comment: Is worth to mention that if you're using DHCP in multiple interfaces you might want to consider using `RouteMetric=xyz` under the `[DHCP]` section instead of the `[Route]` section.

Answer (score 1):

this isn't really a programming question. You'd be better off asking things like this over on StackExchange Unix & Linux.

I had a similar scenario: multiple interfaces using DHCP causing multiple default routes.

What I did, it may work for you too, is to tell the interfaces where we don't want the DHCP routes that we don't want them. In the `.network` file for the interface, add the DHCP `UseRoutes=false` option like this example:

```
[Match]
Name=eno3

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
UseRoutes=false
```

Comment: This for sure helps if you do not want the DHCP interface to be a default route. In the case of the static interface you could just remoe the `Gateway=` and it wouldn't create the route.